# Why does FFTPack 5.1 not give the same complex numbers as Matlab's FFT2 command does?

Tags: fft, matlab, frequency-spectrum, frequency, ifft

I'm doing FFT2 with FFTPack 5.1 and it's working great. But it does not give the same result as Matlab's FFT2 command.

Turning Time domain -> Frequency domain -> Time Domain give the same result as Matlab's

```
ifft2(fft2(X))
```

How to reproduce the [example](https://github.com/DanielMartensson/CControl/blob/master/src/CControl/Documents/Examples/SignalProcessing/ifft2.txt).

```
/*
 ============================================================================
 Name        : ifft2.c
 Author      : <Your Name Here>
 Version     : 1.0
 Copyright   : MIT
 Description : Inverse FFT2 on a matrix
 ============================================================================
 */

#include "CControl/ccontrol.h"

#define row 3
#define column 3

int main() {
    clock_t start, end;
    float cpu_time_used;
    start = clock();

    /* Create X */
    float X[row * column] = { -0.6485,   0.2851,   1.3475,
                               -0.6743, -0.1499, -1.5549,
                                1.4951,   0.4504, -0.4982 };

    /* Do inverse FFT2 */
    fft2(X, row, column);
    ifft2(X, row, column);

    /* Print */
    print(X, row, column);

    end = clock();
    cpu_time_used = ((float)(end - start)) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    printf("\nTotal speed  was %f\n", cpu_time_used);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

This gives the output is exactly the same as the input X. So no problem there.

```
-0.6485001      0.2851001       1.3475002
-0.6742999      -0.1499000      -1.5549001
1.4951000       0.4503998       -0.4982001
```

But if I comment `/* ifft2(X, row, column); */` then the output will look like this. Here im using `rfft2i -> rfft2f`

```
0.0058111       0.0258111       -0.1242458
0.1611111       -0.2950723      0.3444953
0.3681955       -0.2190056      0.0864390
```

If I use the complex version of FFTPack `cfft2i -> cfft2f`, then I will get this

```
Real:
0.0058111       0.0258111       0.0258111
0.1611111       -0.2950723      -0.2190056
0.1611111       -0.2190056      -0.2950723

Imaginary:
0.0000000       -0.1242458      0.1242458
0.3681955       0.3444953       -0.0864390
-0.3681955      0.0864390       -0.3444953
```

While Matlab's `fft2` command will give

```
X =

  -0.6485   0.2851   1.3475
  -0.6743  -0.1499  -1.5549
   1.4951   0.4504  -0.4982

>> fft2(X)
ans =

   0.0523 +      0i   0.2323 - 1.1182i   0.2323 + 1.1182i
   1.4500 + 3.3138i  -2.6556 + 3.1005i  -1.9710 - 0.7780i
   1.4500 - 3.3138i  -1.9710 + 0.7780i  -2.6556 - 3.1005i

>>
```

**Question:**

Why does this happen? Is it different normalization methods inside Matlab's FFT version compared to FFTpack's version?

**Notice:**

If I take the first number of the output `0.0058111` and multiply it with the total elements of `X`, then i will get the same number as Matlab.

```
0.0058111 * row * column = 0.0058111 * 3 * 3 = 0.0058111 * 9 = 0.052300
```

But that's only for the first number.

**Update:**

Okey! Let's begin with a simple example here.
The `ifft2.c` file can be found [here](https://github.com/DanielMartensson/CControl/blob/master/src/CControl/Sources/SignalProcessing/ifft2.c) and the `fft2.c` file can be found here [here](https://github.com/DanielMartensson/CControl/blob/master/src/CControl/Sources/SignalProcessing/fft2.c).

This example below can be found [here](https://github.com/DanielMartensson/CControl/blob/master/src/CControl/Documents/Examples/SignalProcessing/ifft2.txt).

```
#define row 8
#define column 6

int main() {
    clock_t start, end;
    float cpu_time_used;
    start = clock();

    /* Create XR and XI */
    float XR[row * column] = { 0.350465, -0.177253, -0.581183, -0.301331, -0.546504, -2.416981,
                               0.858123,   0.298243, -0.158775, -0.860663, -1.632077,   0.865414,
                             -1.493957,   2.336641, -0.446940,   0.708597,   0.305746, -0.047449,
                             -0.468543,   0.048264, -0.433347,   0.312619, -0.842901,   0.080138,
                               1.770406, -0.824584,   0.620406, -1.679783,   0.136926,   0.717155,
                               0.873513, -0.388835,   0.191366,   1.072161,   1.603772, -1.356124,
                             -1.509112, -0.612916,   0.176142, -1.533731,   0.518523,   2.354984,
                               0.832047, -1.777008, -0.206316, -1.224436,   0.305427, -1.668821 };
    float XI[row * column];

    /* Do inverse FFT2 */
    fft2(XR, XI, row, column);
    ifft2(XR, XI, row, column);

    /* Print */
    print(XR, row, column);
    print(XI, row, column);

    end = clock();
    cpu_time_used = ((float)(end - start)) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    printf("\nTotal speed  was %f\n", cpu_time_used);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

When I run this, the output will give exactly the same as Matlabs.

```
>> ifft2(fft2(A))
ans =

   0.350465  -0.177253  -0.581183  -0.301331  -0.546504  -2.416981
   0.858123   0.298243  -0.158775  -0.860663  -1.632077   0.865414
  -1.493957   2.336641  -0.446940   0.708597   0.305746  -0.047449
  -0.468543   0.048264  -0.433347   0.312619  -0.842901   0.080138
   1.770406  -0.824584   0.620406  -1.679783   0.136926   0.717155
   0.873513  -0.388835   0.191366   1.072161   1.603772  -1.356124
  -1.509112  -0.612916   0.176142  -1.533731   0.518523   2.354984
   0.832047  -1.777008  -0.206316  -1.224436   0.305427  -1.668821
```

But if I only run `fft2`, the result will not be the same. Comment `/* ifft2(XR, XI, row, column); */` and run again. Then the result will look like this

```
Real:
-0.1219269      0.2068767       -0.0494243      0.0860417       0.1312272       0.0860417
-0.0494243      0.2068767       -0.0626739      0.1817200       0.1396072       0.0033626
-0.1028655      -0.1205409      -0.1449811      -0.1417322      0.0206129       0.0990283
0.0492298       0.0212876       0.1923714       -0.0635734      -0.0035284      -0.0333547
-0.1085037      0.0505443       -0.0500256      -0.0654177      0.0245388       -0.0654177
-0.0500256      0.0505443       0.0206129       -0.0333547      -0.0035284      -0.0635734
0.1923714       0.0212876       0.0492298       0.0990283       -0.0626739      -0.1417322
-0.1449811      -0.1205409      -0.1028655      0.0033626       0.1396072       0.1817200

Imag: 
0.0000000       0.0009924       -0.1527970      -0.0218802      0.0000000       0.0218802
0.1527970       -0.0009924      -0.0199693      0.1117011       -0.0153265      -0.2154957
0.2755421       0.0016516       -0.1843305      0.1274773       0.0133355       0.1168035
0.1507516       -0.1103715      0.1050291       -0.0791788      -0.0414177      -0.0406829
0.0000000       -0.1077598      0.1155169       -0.0546637      -0.0000000      0.0546637
-0.1155169      0.1077598       -0.0133355      0.0406829       0.0414177       0.0791788
-0.1050291      0.1103715       -0.1507516      -0.1168035      0.0199693       -0.1274773
0.1843305       -0.0016515      -0.2755421      0.2154957       0.0153264       -0.1117011
```

The matlab result for `fft2(A)`:

```
-5.8525 +       0i    3.9298 +  0.2713i   -0.5142 -  0.9195i    6.2989 +       0i   -0.5142 +  0.9195i
   -7.9919 -  1.8342i   -4.9087 -  4.9024i   -0.1495 -  2.1878i    0.0733 + 12.3531i    3.3826 +  0.8807i
   -3.6888 -  6.4090i    2.7663 -  3.4693i    7.4698 -  0.3057i   12.0890 +  1.3099i    8.1229 -  0.7596i
   -0.8347 +  2.1033i   -4.1666 -  7.5407i   10.8868 -  1.7628i   -4.4665 +  5.1328i   -5.5422 + 10.0631i
    1.5010 +       0i    1.0648 +  0.6503i   -8.3754 -  0.3976i   -4.7438 +       0i   -8.3754 +  0.3976i
   -0.8347 -  2.1033i   -9.8491 +  2.3216i   -5.5422 - 10.0631i   -4.4665 -  5.1328i   10.8868 +  1.7628i
   -3.6888 +  6.4090i    3.9844 -  1.4249i    8.1229 +  0.7596i   12.0890 -  1.3099i    7.4698 +  0.3057i
   -7.9919 +  1.8342i    6.5273 -  1.1829i    3.3826 -  0.8807i    0.0733 - 12.3531i   -0.1495 +  2.1878i

 Column 6:

    3.9298 -  0.2713i
    6.5273 +  1.1829i
    3.9844 +  1.4249i
   -9.8491 -  2.3216i
    1.0648 -  0.6503i
   -4.1666 +  7.5407i
    2.7663 +  3.4693i
   -4.9087 +  4.9024i
```

If you look at the ratio between the first number `-5.8525` from Matlab result, and the first number of the FFTPack result `-0.1219269`.

```
-5.8525/-0.1219269 = 48
```

48 is the same number as `row * column = 8 * 6 = 48`

So that means that all real numbers that don't have an imaginary number, can be multiplied with `row * column`. But if there is an imaginary number included inside the result, then this method will not work.

So my question is simple. I want to turn that result from FFTPack into the same result as Matlab result. How can that be done?

I'm not the author for the GitHub repository.

Comment: They can't be the same since one is real and one is complex (which is correct). Whatever produces a real output must be wrong. Fix that first and worry about the scaling later. Your output must have 18 real numbers. The ones that you are getting (when multiplied by 9) are "sort of"  correct, i.e. they are either the real or imaginary part of the correct solution but the order is wrong and half of them are missing. What does the documentation say?

Comment: @Hilmar Yes, One is real and other is complex. But notice that FFTPack is using complex numbers, they are just comming after the real numbers. "Half" does not missing. It just don't compute the mirror FFT. Here is the documentation: https://github.com/jlokimlin/fftpack5.1/blob/master/doc/FFTPACK5.1.html

Comment: What exactly is your goal? If you want to get the same result as Matlab, you need to create a complex matrix by re-ordering your results using the symmetry properties of the 2D DFT (i.e. $H(-n,-m) = H(n,m)'$ Your result (after scaling) is indeed correct, it's just represented in a somewhat non-intuitive way

Comment: Please include all relevant code in your question. Navigating your GitHub project to find the definition of `fft2` takes too much time. And without that code, we don’t know how you’re using FFTPack, and hence we don’t know what is going wrong. If you want people to help you, make it easy for them to do so.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Hi! I have updated the question.